# for loop inside recursion - Python

Tags: python, recursion

Can anybody please tell me why the function isn't completing the for loop in the code below? What am I missing and how can I make it work?

```
def recur_factorial(n, j=0):
    j += 1
    print('j=',j)
    print('n=', n)
    if n == 1:
        return(1)
    else:
        for i in range(2, n):
            print('i=', i)
            return i * recur_factorial(n = i - 1, j = j)
    print('reached end of function')
```

With this input:

```
recur_factorial(5)
```

I am getting the following output:

```
j= 1
n= 5
i= 2
j= 2
n= 1
2
```

Comment: why do you expect your loop to keep running when you call `return`. return will do just that, it will return from the function. What are you expecting your output to be?

Comment: But should't it return from the function called inside the for loop right back to the for loop? Shouldn't it continue with the step i = 3? I was expecting it to calculate all factorials from 2 to n.

Comment: return does just what it says. it immediately returns from the function. again what is your expected output here? what ae you expecting it to do?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I think he/she doesn't expect his loop to keep running forever; he/she expects it to loop more, e.g. `n` from 5 to 1, or whatever it should be.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I was expecting it to calculate all factorials from 2 to n.

Comment: @daniellga You don't need the for loop.To calculate the factorial of the n element you must have calculated the factorial of n-1 by definition,so if you want to calculate all the factorials of a given range of numbers you just calculate the factorial of n. The result of the factorial for n-1 for example, will occur before you call the recursion for last time

Comment: As sammy posted in his answer you dont need a for loop when using recursion here. this is the key difference in things like function vs iterative programming. if after reading sammys answer if you still cannot solve it then post a comment here and i will show you a solution for this just using recursion.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I give up... How would u create a function, using recursion, that takes n as input and returns a list of all factorials from 2 to n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in a recursive solution you dont use a for loop but instead utilise the functional programing model of using the stack as your loop

```
def recur_factorial(n):
    total = 1
    if n > 1:
        total = n * recur_factorial(n - 1)
    print(total)
    return total


recur_factorial(5)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1
2
6
24
120
```

This hopefully gives you a better idea and if your requirement changes you can just adapt this model to achieve what you need.

**UPDATE**

Just realised in your comment you said the function needs to return a `list` of factorials from 2 to n. so below is updated code to return a list.

```
def recur_factorial(n, factorials=[]):
    if n == 1:
        factorials.append(1)
    else:
        total = n * recur_factorial(n - 1)[-1]
        factorials.append(total)
    return factorials

factorials = recur_factorial(10)
print(factorials)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you! I still don't know why 'return' won't go back to the place right before the function was called, but I think I learned the lesson to avoid using for loops with recursion. I am trying to implement a DFS alghorithm and I ran into a similar problem which originated this post... I will try to adapt it to only use recursion.

Comment: You can think of the return statement acting like exit. It basically says stop and exit this function x

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out the concrete problem is that you return within the for loop which ends the function completely.

However, assuming that you would like to recursively implement the calculation of a factorial I'd suggest to revisit your code completely. the real 'issue' is not the for loop and the return statement but the way you approach this.

Basically what you are doing is mixing a recursive and an iterative implemention. The iterative implementation uses a for loop and then does not need to call itself (because it 'knows' how many times to run the loop (i.e. n times) and do the single steps in the calculations).

the recursive implementation does not use a for loop and it does not 'know' how many times to run the individual calculation steps (not even at run time when the function is called the first time and the n is set). Therefore, think of a way to implement it recursively with no for loop at all! Recursively is more thinking but only 4 lines of code. But it will be more helpful if you try to come up with the solution yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to improve my original code with your advices.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do factorial of a number but while going through your code, i found a bug and fixed it. Here goes the updated working code,

```
def recur_factorial(n, j=0):
j += 1
print('j=',j)
print('n=', n)    
if n == 1:
    return(1)
else:
    stop = n
    for i in range(2, stop + 1):
        print('i=', i)
        return n * recur_factorial(n = n - 1, j = j)
print('reached end of function') ##This statement will not execute since the function is returning before this statement
```